# assistance with setting up team city

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

This is very much a beginners question. I am very new to team city and need assistance in getting it setup and integrated with TFS source control for a .net c# solution.

I use TFS for source control and now looking at team city to handle continous integration. Fro starters I just want a basic setup when a user checks in to TFS, a CI build is triggered on team city and if it or associated tests fail, email alert is sent.

The team city server and TFS server can communicate with each other and on the same network. I have installed team city but no configuration has been carried out.

Any assistance of pointing in the correct direct as to how I can accomplish the basis setup suggested above would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Teamcity has nice wizard and documentation.

Comment: Hi Amateur, You got any tutorial or steps to integrate team city with TFS, Can you share it...

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements are the basics of what TeamCity will do for you. To get started configuring TeamCity, jump into the Administration section from the link at the top of the page and the user interface will direct you fairly well to create a new project and a new build configuration within that project.

For more detailed information see the official [TeamCity documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/TeamCity+Documentation) which contains [details about configuring TFS in TeamCity](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Team+Foundation+Server).

Comment: For TeamCity version 8 go to http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Team+Foundation+Server